# Speeding up SQLite program with 100s of triggers and lots of WITH RECURSIVE

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a large SQLite program with many triggers (400) and many `WITH RECURSIVE` statements in the triggers.  It is starting to run a bit slowly and the sluggishness seems to increase as I add triggers and as the `WITH RECURSIVE` statements get longer.

I've tightened up the SQL to eliminate unnecessary crud, but it is getting to the point where even in its leanest form it is still slow.

The SQL triggers are fixed, so what would be ideal is if there was some way to "compile" SQL code with fixed triggers and with recursive statements. I've even toyed with the notion of automating the reverse engineering C++ code to act as an ORM for the SQL, but this seems like it'd be a pain.  So, does anyone have any tricks to speed up sqlite programs (hints to give to SQLite via functions, gcc compile options, etc.) that don't require porting them over to a compiled language like C++?

Comment: When all you have is a hammer everything looks like a nail.

Comment: `WITH RECURSIVE` just cannot be fast. This sounds as if you're trying to do too much in SQL.

Comment: "I've tightened up the SQL to eliminate unnecessary crud, but it is getting to the point where even in its leanest form it is still slow." Odds are if you have 400 triggers, you haven't eliminated much of the unessacary crud. There is no such thing as 'leanest form' with 400 triggers (unless we're talking about the leanest form of the two ton man?).  Tis a bit insane, what are you accomplishing with this many triggers?

Comment: I've designed all app logic in SQL to allow for quick prototyping and for all data to be accessible via queries.  This allows me to substitute in and out triggers on the fly, which is really useful to make an app customizable.  But the idea is that I'll be freezing certain versions of the app, and in their frozen state they need to be faster.